# redirect() not directing to proper view

Tags: django

I am trying to use the `redirect()` method redirect to my `index` view upon successful submission of the form found in my `register` view.
I have the following `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from users import views as usersViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', usersViews.index, name = 'index'),

    path('register/', usersViews.register, name = 'regsister'),

]
```

and the following `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('signed up')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() # save form? to db?
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            return redirect("index") #this statement is not working
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm() 
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', {'registrationForm':form})
```

Upon submission of the form I am being redirected to "/register/index.html" and not "/" (index page). Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Looks like there is another `urls.py` with a `path` named `'index'`.

Comment: The only `urls.py` I have exists in the main project folder, I did not make one for the app

Comment: are you sure it is the marked statement, and that the redirect does not trigger a *second* redirect.

Comment: Are you sure the form is being submitted to this view at all? What is the `action` attribute in the form HTML?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I feel foolish...thanks would have never figured that out. Just watched a tutorial on building a registration/login system and attempted to go back and do it myself without the video, left that part out.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with reverse:

```
from django.urls import reverse
return redirect(reverse('app_name:view_name'), {'registrationForm':form})
```